# How to check more value in if statement VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, comparison

I don't know how to do this, but i'm trying to make a code that checks value more than 10 in VB.NET
(Idk what it's called)

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If currency = 10 Then
            Button2.Enabled = False
            Button3.Enabled = True
            clickpoints = clickpoints + 1
        ElseIf currency = +10 Then ' Check points more than 10
            Button2.Enabled = False
            Button3.Enabled = True
            clickpoints = clickpoints + 1
            currency = currency - 10
        Else
            MsgBox("Not enough points")
        End If
    End Sub
```

can someone help me?

Comment: `ElseIf currency > 10 Then`

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Comment: Consider following [**a tutorial for the language**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk24xdbe(v=vs.100).aspx). What you're asking is described in [**Using Expressions to Compare Values**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf71d2dk(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @VisualVincent Okay!

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of redundant code, your code could be rewritten as:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Currency < 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Not enough points")
    Else
        Button2.Enabled = False
        Button3.Enabled = True
        clickpoints = clickpoints + 1
        If Currency > 10 Then
            Currency = Currency - 10
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```